# Why does iterating over this empty object cause a core dump?

Tags: c++, database, iterator, coredump

I'm working on this iterating program right now, and I'm running into trouble when I try to iterate over an empty list. Here's the code of interest:

```cpp
// part A
DoublyLinkedList<int> myListOneNode;

myListOneNode.insertLast(42);
cout << "TestIterationTricky test #1, the next line should display 42" << endl;
stringstream ss;
//see if we can just iterator through one item.
for (auto i : myListOneNode) {
    cout << i << " ";
    ss << i << " ";
}
cout << endl;
checkTest("TestIterationTricky test #1", "42 ", ss.str()); // is ss equal to "42 " ?
ss.str("");
```

```cpp
// part B
DoublyLinkedList<int> myListEmpty;
cout << "TestIterationTricky test #2, the next line shouldn't display anything" << endl;
//see if we can just iterator through one item.
for (auto i : myListEmpty) {
    cout << i << " ";
    ss << i << " ";
}
cout << endl;
checkTest("TestIterationTricky test #2", "", ss.str()); // is ss equal equal to "" ?
ss.str("");
```

Part A in this excerpt works fine, no errors.

Part B, however, results in a segmentation fault. The program crashes as soon as it reaches the definition of the `for` loop.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to show the definition of `DoublyLinkedList`

Comment: Unless you know what the bug is, how can you be sure about what is or is not relevant? Make a [mre] and you'll not only be sure you have all of the relevant code, but in paring the code down so that you provide only the relevant code you'll probably reduce the noise enough that you can spot and fix the bug yourself.

Comment: What you describe implies that `DoublyLinkedList` is not implementing iterators correctly for an empty list. Either its `begin()`/`end()` methods are returning invalid iterators, or the iterators themselves are faulty in how they operate. But we can't see the implementation either way, so we can't help you fix it. Please update your question to provide the relevant implementation code for `DoublyLinkedList`.